# Updating Total in One Table with Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql

I am just learning about foreign keys.  I am simplifying my tables to this:

```
Table:  item
Columns:  item_id (PK), qty

Table:  item_change_log
Columns:  id (PK), item_id (indexed), change_value
```

Both tables are INNODB.

Everytime a change in the item levels is made, the quantity changed is logged in the `item_change_log.change_value`.  I want the change_value to automatically add/subtract `item.qty`.

The intended behavior:

User creates Item X.  `item.item_id = X, qty = 0`.  No record is made in item_change_log yet.
User changes quantity of X on hand to 2.  `item_change_log:  id = 1, item_id = X, change_value = 2`.  This change_value automatically increases `item.qty = 2` via foreign keys.

I know how to make the foreign keys for the item id's see each other, but I don't know how to add the "math" element, or if that is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a trigger, but which?

- Since it is the item_change_log table your user actually modifies,
  you need a trigger on item_change_log
- Since you allways insert into item_change_log, you need an INSERT
  trigger
- Since You only want to update item only, if the insert to item_change_log
  really works, you want an AFTER INSERT trigger

So here we go

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_item_table AFTER INSERT ON item_change_log
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE item SET qty=qty+NEW.qty WHERE item_id=NEW.item_id;
  END;
```

Comment: +1 But there's no need for `BEGIN` and `END` here since it is a one-line statement.

Comment: @netcoder Ofcourse you are right, I think my fingers type the "FOR EACH ROW BEGIN" at the beginning of a trigger without any interaction with the brain. NOT updating my code - this would kill the context for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is not handled via foreign keys. Instead, look into [creating a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) on the `item_change_log` table that will update `item` whenever a row is inserted.